Have to add magic number to length in .Substring
I have a data structure that I read over UDP, and it looks like this:
$T_DATA,17,<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TData id="Channel 4">
  <Meta>
    <InstrumentID>17</InstrumentID>
    <DatagramID>4</DatagramID>
    <Timestamp>2024-09-10 15:00:57.480</Timestamp>
  </Meta>
  <Data>
    <Value ID="1" type="0">108.33</Value>
    <Value ID="2" type="0">-39</Value>
    <Value ID="3" type="0">422.9</Value>
  </Data>
</TData>
????

I want to remove everything before <Tdata and everything after </Tdata>
My code that does exactly that looks like this:
static string StripNonXmlContent(string input)
{
    // Find the start of the XML tag and ignore anything before it
    string stopString = "</TData>";
    int xmlStartIndex = input.IndexOf("<TData");
    // TODO: Explain magic number 7. Without it return string gets too short.
    int xmlStopIndex = input.LastIndexOf(stopString) + stopString.Length + 7;

    // If both the start and end of the XML are found
    if (xmlStartIndex >= 0 && xmlStopIndex >= 0)
    {
        // Extract everything between <TData> and </TData>
        return input.Substring(xmlStartIndex, (xmlStopIndex - xmlStartIndex));
    }

    // If no valid XML structure is found, return the input as is
    return input;
}

In the beginning my last index looked like: xmlStopIndex = input.LastIndexOf(stopString) + stopString.Length;, but that cut the return too short, the last line became just <T. and through trial and error I found out that by adding the magic number 7 I got it to work.
Can somebody explain to me why this is?

Further investigation.
The string actually looks like this:
???$?T?C?L?I?E?N?T?_?D?A?T?A?,?1?7?,?<???x?m?l? ?v?e?r?s?i?o?n?=?"?1?.?0?"???>?
?<?T?D?a?t?a? ?i?d?=?"?C?h?a?n?n?e?l? ?5?"?>?
? ? ? ? ?<?M?e?t?a?>?
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?<?I?n?s?t?r?u?m?e?n?t?I?D?>?1?7?<?/?I?n?s?t?r?u?m?e?n?t?I?D?>?
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?<?D?a?t?a?g?r?a?m?I?D?>?5?<?/?D?a?t?a?g?r?a?m?I?D?>?
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?<?T?i?m?e?s?t?a?m?p?>?2?0?2?4?-?0?9?-?1?0? ?1?5?:?3?4?:?5?6?.?4?8?6?<?/?T?i?m?e?s?t?a?m?p?>?
? ? ? ? ?<?/?M?e?t?a?>?
? ? ? ? ?<?D?a?t?a?>?
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?<?V?a?l?u?e? ?I?D?=?"?1?"? ?t?y?p?e?=?"?0?"?>?1?0?5?.?7?4?<?/?V?a?l?u?e?>?
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?<?V?a?l?u?e? ?I?D?=?"?2?"? ?t?y?p?e?=?"?0?"?>?-?3?9?<?/?V?a?l?u?e?>?
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?<?V?a?l?u?e? ?I?D?=?"?3?"? ?t?y?p?e?=?"?0?"?>?3?3?5?.?4?<?/?V?a?l?u?e?>?
? ? ? ? ?<?/?D?a?t?a?>?
?<?/?T?D?a?t?a?>?
????

And there are seven ? inside the string </TData> which explains why I have to add 7 to make this work.
There must be something wrong with how I read the data. It looks like this:
byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint);
string receivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes, 0, receiveBytes.Length);
Console.WriteLine($"Received data from {remoteEndPoint}:");
Console.WriteLine(receivedData);


When I test this locally it works as expected without the + 9, and throws an exception with it.  Perhaps the input string is different than what you show here?  Can you include that input string literal in a [mcve] which can be independently tested to demonstrate the problem?

You should keep the <xml version.. > portion as well. That's still valid xml that the parser can read, understand, and use.

Could also be a UDP issue because data packets are not guaranteed and somehow end up with more characters like newline or whitespace. Try trimming?

When I test your code it works perfectly fine without +9, you can see it here.

@David
I updated my question. I inspected the code and found out how the string really looked like. It turns out my Terminal prettified the output.

@JoelCoehoorn, good point, thanks!

@JoachimSpange: My first thought is that perhaps the encoding isn't ASCII.  Can the source of the data confirm the encoding?  You might also try different encodings and see what results you get.

That updated string looks like what you get when you try to display UTF16 as if it was ANSI/ASCII

@MatthewWatson It's true that I use ASCII. But UTF8 and UTF16 looks the same

Isn't it kind of scary to send xml directly over UDP? If your string is UTF16 encoded it takes 720 bytes, already over the maximum safe size of 508 bytes. And the size can depend on the data, so it is possible that only some packets are dropped, making the problem harder to detect.

What's the actual byte array you get, before decoding? What are the byte values behind the ? ?

@canton7 byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint);  returns a byte[780].
string receivedData = Encoding.UTF16.GetString(receiveBytes, 0, receiveBytes.Length);
Is a long string, but this is a part of it:
\0\0\u0003\u0004\0$\0M\0D\0M\0C\0L\0I\0E\0N\0T\0_\0D\0A\0T\0A\0,\01\07\0,\0<\0?\0x\0m\0l\0 \0v\0e\0r\0>\0\n\0 \0 \0 \0 \0 \0 \0 \0 \0<\0T\0i\0m\0e\0s\0t\0a\0m\0p\0>\02\00\02\04\0-\00\09\0-\01\01\0 \00\08\0:\04\07\0:\04\01\0.\05\05\04\0<\0/\0T\0i\0m\0e\0s\0t\0a\0m\0p\0>\0\n\0

@JoachimSpange I'm interested in the byte values, not the characters once it's been turned into a string. So the contents of that byte[780]. Use Convert.ToHexString(receiveBytes) if that's easier.

The fact that decoding as UTF-16 still gives every other character as \0 does rather imply that it's UTF-32, but looking at the raw bytes will tell us much more. Converting bytes to text using an encoding throws away information, if the encoding is not correct

@canton7 you are so right.
the HEX string contains
00-00-03-06-00-24-00-4D-00-44-00-4D-00-43-00-4C-00-49-00-45-00-4E-00-54-00-5F-00-44-00-41-00-54-00-41-00-2C-00-31-00-37-00-2C-00-3C-00-3F-00-78-00-6D-00-6C-00-20-00-76-00-65-00-72-00-73-00-69-00-6F-00-6E-00-3D-00-22-00-31-00-2E-00-30-00-22-00-3F-00-3E-00-0A-00-3C-00-4D-00-64-00-6D-00-44-00-61-00-74-75-00-65-00-3E-00-0A-00-20-00-20-00-20-00-20-00-3C-00-2F-00-44-00-61-00-74-00-61-00-3E-00-0A-00-3C-00-2F-00-4D-00-64-00-6D-00-44-00-61-00-74-00-61-00-3E-00-0A-FF-FF-FF-FF
I figured out that BigEndianUnicode solves the formatting

Huh, that doesn't look like UTF-32, that looks like UTF-16. And BigEndianUnicode is UTF-16. I should have clocked the fact that Encoding.UTF16.GetString(receiveBytes, 0, receiveBytes.Length) is obviously not something you actually tried to run, as Encoding.UTF16 does not exist.

@canton7 yes Encoding.UTF16.GetString(receiveBytes, 0, receiveBytes.Length); throws an error. But BigEndianUnicode does not.

Encoding.UTF16 is not valid C#. The Encoding class does not have a UTF16 property. See here and here. There's no way that code compiled, let alone "threw an error", let alone produced a string where every other character is \0 as you claimed above.

Looks like your data is arriving as UTF16, but you're reading it as ASCII. Try reading the data as UTF16.

The issue here was that I was running my code with dotnet run in the VSCode terminal. It pretty printed the output for me, so it visually looked correct, while it was full of non-printable characters. This was because I did not have the correct format. I tried ASCII/UTF8/UTF32, but it was BigEndianUnicode or UTF16 that was correct. I discovered this by looking at the actual HEX string with Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(receiveBytes));
Here is a snippet of the output:
00-00-03-06-00-24-00-4D-00-44-00-4D-00-43-00-4C-00-49-00-45-00-4E-00-54- 
00-5F-00-44-00-41-00-54-00-41-00-2C-00-31-00-37-00-2C-00-3C-00-3F-00-78- 
00-6D-00-6C-00-20-00-76-00-65-00-72-00-73-00-69-00-6F-00-6E-00-3D-00-22- 
00-31-00-2E-00-30-00-22-00-3F-00-3E-00-0A-00-3C-00-4D-00-64-00-6D-00-44- 
00-61-00-74-00-61-00-20-00-69-00-64-00-3D-00-22-00-43-00-68-00-61-00-6E- 
00-6E-00-65-00-6C-00-20-00-35-00-22-

Using the Debug Console of VSCode I could see the Console.Writeline another way, and there it became obvious that the formatting was wrong. Here is a snippet of the bad format:
? ? ? ? ?<?D?a?t?a?>?
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?<?V?a?l?u?e? ?I?D?=?"?1?"? ?t?y?p?e?=?"?0?"?>?9?4?.?7?5? 
<?/?V?a?l?u?e?>?
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?<?V?a?l?u?e? ?I?D?=?"?2?"? ?t?y?p?e?=?"?0?"?>?-?4?0?
<?/?V?a?l?u?e?>?
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?<?V?a?l?u?e? ?I?D?=?"?3?"? ?t?y?p?e?=?"?0?"?>?2?0?5?5?.?3?
<?/?V?a?l?u?e?>?
? ? ? ? ?<?/?D?a?t?a?>?

And just by counting the number of ?s I found my magic number 7, which my question was all about.
Here is my code:
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(Port);
    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    while (true)
    {
        byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint);
        // Data transmitted in Big Endian format, where the most significant byte comes first.
        string cleanData = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(receiveBytes, 0, receiveBytes.Length);

        // Strip out any non-UTF-16 printable characters
        cleanData = Regex.Replace(cleanData, @"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]", string.Empty);

        // Remove any unwanted characters before "$MDMCLIENT_DATA"
        cleanData = Regex.Replace(cleanData, @"^[^\$]*", string.Empty);

        Console.WriteLine($"Cleaned data from {remoteEndPoint}:");
        Console.WriteLine(cleanData);
    }
  }
}

So in the end:
Format correctly!
